skopt.gbrt_minimize (gradient boosted regression trees) - how does it calculate the gradient of the loss function if it is not differentiable?
I am optimising 11 parameters for a Jansen & Rit whole-brain model as follows:
search_space = [
Integer(1, 10, name="A"), Integer(10, 40, name="B"), Integer(90, 200, name="C"), etc...
]
gbrt_minimize(find_bold_loss, search_space, n_calls=80, n_initial_points=32, initial_point_generator='sobol').
What I don't understand, is my loss function is highly complex and non-differentiable, as it first needs to run the model (which uses the Euler method and introduces Gaussian noise on each iteration). So, how does gbrt work if it is unable to calculate the gradient of the loss at each iteration? I'm new to skopt and GBRT, so some in-depth explanation would be appreciated!
N.B. I have run the model with gbrt and it works well (better than bayesian optimisation), so it must be doing something right...

I'm not deeply familiar with the package or it's source code, but from the documentation I assume:
It doesn't (need to) compute gradients of your function. It's fitting gbdt's to (increasing) sets of inputs x for which the output y of your function has been computed (some initial set together with earlier iterations of the optimizer). And that involves gradients, but it's of the standard MSE loss of the gbdt fitting procedure.
